# Extracting the first 13,000 results of a search query with Custom Search Engine JSON API

Tags: python-3.x, google-search, google-custom-search, google-search-api

I am developing an application (Python 3.x) in which I need to collect the first 13,000 results of a CSE query using one search keyword (from result index 1 to 13,000). For a free version of CSE JSON API (I have tried it), I can only get the first 10 results per query or 100 results per day (by repeating the same query while incrementing the index) otherwise it gives an error (HttpError 400.....returned Invalid Value) when the result index exceeds 100. Is there any option (paid/free) that I can deploy to achieve the objective?

Answer (score 0):

Custom Search JSON API is limited to a max depth of 100 results per query, so you'll need to find a different API or devise some solution to modify the query to divide up the result set into smaller parts